# How to view document UUID in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I can view all the documents in a table with this:

```
r.db('database').table('users')
```

But how can I list the uuid for each document/user?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list only the ids, you can use the `map` function:

```
r.db('database').table('users').map(r.row("id"))
```

other option would be the to use `pluck` (this will include the field name in the return object):

```
r.db('database').table('users').pluck("id")
```